# Como sumo los componentes de cada fila de una matriz con numpy?

Tags: numpy

Buenas, tengo que hacer un problema de matrices con el numpy pero no encuentro forma de solucionarlo. Agradeceria vuestra ayuda. 
El problema es el siguiente:

Programad una función suma_fila(mat) que dado un numpy array de rango 2 mat (una matriz) retorne un numpy array con la suma de cada una de sus filas.

Entrada:

```
suma_fila(np.array([[1, 0, -1], [3, 4, 1]]))
```

Solución:

```
array([0, 8])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes usar `numpy.sum(a, axis=None, dtype=None, out=None, keepdims=False)`
con `axis = 1`

Es decir:

```
import numpy as np

array = np.array([[1, 0, -1], [3, 4, 1]])
salida = np.sum(array, axis=1)
print(salida)
```

Salida:

```
[0, 8]
```

Comment: De acuerdo!! Muchisimas gracias!! :)

Comment: @MarcTC Si mi respuesta te ayudo marcalá como correcta